# Ingestion of Dynamics 365 web services in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, dynamics-365

I am new in NiFi(flow management tool). I want to ingest web services data from dynamics 365 in hdfs for that I am using `InvokeHTTP` configured with the remote URL. But I am getting:

> "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

InvokeHTTP config:

[image: InvokeHTTP config]

SSLContext Controller service config:

[image: SSLContext Controller service config]

Comment: Hello, please provide text representation of the configuration instead of a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for according your time. Sorry i just saw i had a message. As i said i am new but i don't think i can provide you text configuration of the processors. i will try to show you my sslcontext ControllerService config.

Comment: The error means that java (nifi) can't validate certificate provided by dynamics host. Usually it's because there's a self-signed certificate used for https or the name in certificate does not correspond to host name.

Comment: ok I see thanks. So what do i have to do ?